# jQuery - selecting only every 2nd element with .each?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to only select every 2nd element with the .each() function? If not, what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector:

```
$("yourSelector:odd").each(function() {
    // Will be called on every second element.
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it only gets the 2nd element, it could include the 4th, 6th, etc..

Comment: @ace, it does indeed include the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc., i.e. *every* second element, as the questioner apparently wants :)

Comment: ah, i'm confused with his question. :)

Answer (score 7):

This might help:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    if(index%2)
       alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `if(index==1)` matches *only* the 2nd element... I think he meant every other (2nd, 4th, 6th etc).

Comment: For some reason when I use index%2 it crashes visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can use :nth-child() selector.

```
$("selector:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: Please be careful with this one since it also counts other elements that are children, e.g. in `<div><a></a><b></b></div>` then `$('b:nth-child(2)')` will contain just the `<b>` whilst you normally would also get this result. So basically it's not exactly each second matched item. Also it will only match exactly the second child, not 'every second element'. Compare: `$('b:nth-child(2)', "<div><a></a><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b><b>d</b></div>")` will contain `a`, `$('b:odd', "<div><a></a><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b><b>d</b></div>")` will contain `b` and `d`.

Comment: Yes. Your explanation is correct, I misunderstood the question. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fetch particular element/node or tag in loop for e.g.

```
<p class="weekday" data-today="monday">Monday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="tuesday">Tuesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="wednesday">Wednesday</p>
<p class="weekday" data-today="thursday">Thursday</p>
```

So, from above code loop is executed and we want particular field to select for that we have to use jQuery selection that can select only expecting element from above loop so, code will be

```
$('.weekdays:eq(n)');
```

e.g.

```
$('.weekdays:eq(0)');
```

as well as by other method

```
$('.weekday').find('p').first('.weekdays').next()/last()/prev();
```

but first method is more efficient when `HTML <tag>` has unique class name.

NOTE:Second method is use when their is no class name in target element or node.

for more follow https://api.jquery.com/eq/